# WCF Service as a mediator between two applications

Tags: wcf

I want to develop a WCF application which acts as middleware between its client and in turn it passes that request to **Controller device** by transforming data as a request.

It should get response which in turn it transfers to Client. After that Controller device can send unsolicited messages at any point of time to its second end point. How I can achieve this required functionality inside single WCF Service? Request and response is just xml/json string data.

[image]

Comment: There's nothing "just" about xml/json. What format, what protocol, what schema? WCF would help if the service needs to support SOAP over HTTP, or if you needed a binary protocol. Otherwise you can build an self-hosted Web API service that, by default, accepts JSON and calls the device. Apart from that, the question is *very* broad.

Comment: Binding is HTTP from one end.For another end its TCP Socket which should be able to communicate as a request sender and also as a listener if any message comes in.Is there any way I can replace TCP socket with any kind of WCF feature?

Comment: HTTP runs over TCP.  WCF just like *any* other TCP networking technology uses sockets. If you *don't* want SOAP, you *don't* need WCF nor will you gain anything by using it. This question is very broad

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos for reply but for my scenario this WCF service requires to be self hosted which should be called by a client over http and on the other hand it must call third application using TCP which should be always listening from TCP end also it should be able to send any request coming from http end point and pass it over to TCP endpoint. so its WCF service with two endpoints but I am not completely aware about how the TCP end point should behave based on its requirement.

Comment: And that other application will also use TCP. HTTP is a protocol that runs on top of TCP. Saying that one end is HTTP and the other TCP makes no sense. I suspect you should understand what each thing means first. Besides you *can* have a self-hosted Web API endpoint just like you can have a self-hosted WCF endpoint. Web API will be simpler. You can even start an HttpListener class and handle all of the communication in code without any other framework support

Comment: Unless you mean that the *device* uses some unspecified binary TCP protocol and you want to expose an HTTP API for it? Again, the same. Everything works. The code that talks to the device will be the same. What changes is whether you have an AbcController (Web API) or AbcService (WCF) class to receive client requests